# How to get the difference value of two column from .dat-file?

Tags: python

| Dy | MxT | MnT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 88 | 59 |
| 2 | 79 | 63 |
| 3 | 77 | 55 |

I have `weather.dat` file having weather data. First column is day number and 2nd column is max temp & 3rd column is min temp. I need to compare row by row that in which day the the difference in max temp & min temp is minimum. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference between the max and min temp for each row and keep a variable as answer which has the value of minimum difference. Keep comparing the answer variable with the max temp and min temp value, if the difference value is lower than the current answer value update answer. Do it for all rows, you will get the required result.

OR

Make a new column for [MxT]-[MnT] values and hence find the minimum value using .min()